# Cypress tries to access cypress.config.js instead of .ts and tries to locate a file from a mixed up path

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, nomachine-nx, cypress-configuration

Within an NX mono repo I have an Angular app on which I run component tests via Cypress.
I sporadically keep getting the following error in the cypress app, when a test reruns after code changes in the testing code:

> Your configFile threw an error from: cypress.config.js
>
> We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed.

When searching the repo for a `cypress.config.js` file I do only find `cypress.config.ts` files since the whole NX repo only uses TypeScript.

Anyways, this is the content of my cypress.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { nxComponentTestingPreset } from '@nx/angular/plugins/component-testing';

export default defineConfig(nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename));
```

I've tried to solve the problem by changing the config like so:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { nxComponentTestingPreset } from '@nx/angular/plugins/component-testing';

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    ... nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename),
    devServer: {
      ... nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename).devServer,
      options: {
        projectConfig: {
          ... nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename).devServer.options.projectConfig,
          root: 'apps/angular-app'
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

But this did not solve the problem.

Also, the error that stack trace reports, is delivering a strange behaviour by mixing up file paths. It actually doubles the path to the `component-index.html` file:

> Error: ENOENT:
>
> no such file or directory, utime
> '/Users/USER/projects/frontends/apps/angular-app/Users/USER/projects/frontends/apps/angular-app/cypress/support/component-index.html'
> at utimesSync (node:fs:2047:3)

Could the reason be, that I am using a newer version of Angular? When starting the Cypress testing app through `USER@machine angular-app % npx cypress open` I receive the following warning:

> Warning: Component Testing Mismatched Dependencies
>
> We detected that you have versions of dependencies that are not
> officially supported:
>
> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic. Expected ^=13.0.0 || ^=14.0.0 ||
> ^=15.0.0, found 16.0.1. If you're experiencing problems, downgrade
> dependencies and restart Cypress.
>
> Blockquote

Comment: What does the `nxComponentTestingPreset` do?

Answer (score 3):

According to the source, the syntax should be

```js
export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    ...nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename)
    // add your own config here
  }
})
```

so in the initial attempt you are missing the `component: {...}` wrapper.

I think the doubled-path is due to unwinding already resolved paths inside the config, you can check the paths given by console logging `nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename)`.

All paths given to `component: {...}` should be relative, not absolute.